# Wall switch no longer used, how to cover it

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch

I have replaced a ceiling fan in my home that had a separate hot wire for a light. The new fan has a remote control for the light & fan motor.  The old fan was controlled from a 5-gang wall switch.  Switch 2 was for the light, position 3 had a fan speed control.  The other switches are still in use for other lights.  I want to remove 2 & 3, to avoid confusion on how to operate the new fan. Does anyone know of either a safe insert to cover the openings in the switch plate when I remove the switches, or a source for a new wall plate? Yes, I have googled to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a ["switch dummy"](https://www.google.com/search?q=dummy+switch&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS590US590&oq=switch+dummy&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.9712j0j4&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=zwsvvzabxdUS-M%3A). Also commonly called a "switch blank", "blank insert" and "blank filler".

The big box stores may not carry this item, if not, electrical supply house should have available.

Comment: Also commonly called a "[switch blank](https://www.google.com/search?q=switch+blank)", "blank insert" and  "blank fillter", and they are commonly carried by the big box stores, at least in my area. They are available in both traditional toggle switch size as well as the larger Decora style. I've also seen [duplex outlet fillers](http://www.kyleswitchplates.com/duplex-outlet-blank-filler-insert-for-switch-plates-leviton-41087-2bnk/),  but those seem to be harder to find.

Comment: @Johnny thanks for the alternate name suggestions, edited.